# Disclosure indicator out of custom cell bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, disclosure

I have a custom cell with enabled `disclosure indicator`. Enabled throw the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
```

To create an illusion of space between cells I have created a `UIImageView` inside my cell.

I was expecting that disclosure will be inside new cell but it is not.

My layout setup :

[image]

and how it looks like:

[image]

Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Cell content is different than accessory view. [Take a closer look at cell.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting that disclosure will be inside new cell but it is not.

It **is** inside cell, but it seems outside to you because it is outside image view.

We need to extend the image view below disclosure indicator.
I did a simple trick of setting leading space **constraint to negative value** as:

[image]

(Above are the constrains of green view, in your case image!)

I also added disclosure indicator from `.xib` instead of code as:

[image]

In `.xib` it will show like above picture, but it works when we run as:
[image]

Instead of adding image, I've added `UIView` with green colour, this is just to implement faster.
You can do same with `UIImageView`.

Comment: cool! works perfect! can you explain please why it is minus 33 ... not 30 and not 40 :) please

Comment: @Almazini It's suggested value by auto layout!

Comment: Unable to do this in Xcode 11.1. Views display inside content view is now limited to content view even with negative constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have added this background in the contentView of the cell – you can see that in the overview on the left in IB.

Try to set the background programmatically, i.e.

```
cell.backgroundView = yourCustomView
```

Comment: This also works, **but** it needs lot of programming to add constraints to the `yourCustomView`!